# Show that the identity matrix $I$ must have norm $1$.

Tags: matrices

I am trying to understand why the identity matrix $I$ must have a norm $1$, for any choice of matrix-norm $|\cdot|$?  How would i show this?

Comment: What is your definition of matrix-norm? It isn't true for any arbitrary norm on some space space of matrices.

Comment: Not only it *must have norm $1$*. It *has* norm $1$.

Comment: yes it has norm 1.

Comment: If your norm satifies $N(a \cdot b) = N(a) N(b)$, then $N(I) = N(I \cdot I) = N(I)^2$, so $N(I) = 1$ (as it can't be 0).

Comment: @vonbrand It doesn't have to satisfy that property, only $N(ab) \leq N(a)N(b)$.

Comment: @user67411 Can you give us a link to the text you are using / state in full the definition of "matrix norm" that the text gives?

Comment: its on a question sheet from uni for a badly organised new course! maybe just a bad question, no extra conditions apart from it is a matrix norm on K^(n*n)

Answer (score 10):

Unless I am missing something, this is not necessarily the case. Take your favorite matrix norm $|\cdot|$ (suppose that it gives $|I| = 1$), and define a new norm $\|\cdot\| = \pi|\cdot|$. Then $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm with $\|I\| = \pi$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ If you are including the submultiplicativeness in the definition of your matrix norm (The definition of a matrix norm does not need to include the submultiplicative property), again pick your now favorite submultiplicative matrix norm $|\cdot|$ with $|I| = 1$. Then, $\|\cdot\| = \pi|\cdot|$ is a submultiplicative matrix norm ($\|AB\| = \pi|AB| \leq \pi |A||B| \leq \pi |A| \pi|B| = \|A\|\|B\|$) with $\|I\| = \pi$.

Comment: I think matrix norms have to at least be sub-multiplicative  $|AB| \leq |A||B|$

Comment: the text i am reading says it is 1!

Comment: i was wondering why i cannot find an further information on this... so confused been bugging me for a few days now

Comment: @TomHarris But the norm $\pi|\cdot|$ is submultiplicative whenever $|\cdot|$ is submultiplicative?

Comment: @LordSoth Yeah, sorry I thought you were using $\pi$ for an arbitrary constant (no idea why, it's the least arbitrary greek letter!). I was trying to make the point that we at least require $|I| \geq 1$. I think the OP must have some extra conditions in their definition of matrix norm that they're not telling us.

Comment: there was no extra conditions, maybe just a badly worded question..

Answer (score 10):

As many others have pointed out, the matrix norm of $I$ is not necessarily equal to $1$. In fact, if $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm $c\|\cdot\|$ is also a matrix norm for any $c\ge1$.

Yet, if your matrix norm is submultiplicative, we have $0<\|I\|=\|I^2\|\le\|I\|^2$ and hence $\|I\|\ge1$, but strict inequality may still occur. E.g. the Frobenius norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ is submultiplicative, but $\|I_n\|_F=\sqrt{n}>1$ when $n>1$.

If your textbook is not erred, it is perhaps talking about an *induced* matrix norm, i.e. one defined by $\|A\|=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\color{red}{\|}Ax\color{red}{\|}}{\color{red}{\|}x\color{red}{\|}}$ for some vector norm $\color{red}{\|\cdot\|}$ defined on $K^n$. In this case, it is straight from the definition that $\|I\|=1$.